# How to properly format System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException with NLog

Tags: ado.net, nlog

When I log a `SqlException` with NLog, many of its important properties such as Stored procedure name are missing from the formatted exception.

What would be the most efficient way to log a `SqlException` with NLog?

Answer (score 1):

You could write the extra info into properties. The fluent interface is the most suitable in that case.

```
using NLog.Fluent;

...

var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
try
{

}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    Log.Error().Exception(ex)
        .Message("Error in DB")
        .Property("command-text", sqlCommand.CommandText)
        .Property("command-parameters", 
            string.Join(",", sqlCommand.Parameters.Cast<SqlParameter>().Select(p => p.ParameterName + "=" + p.Value)))
        .Write();
}
```

Usage in the config:

`${event-properties:command-text}` and `${event-properties:command-parameters}`